# Connecting to host Cosmos emulator from Docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, azure-cosmosdb

I have a .net application running in a docker container via docker compose. I'm using a Windows machine with Docker Desktop running Linux containers.

The application connects to a Cosmos instance. The account key is set to the emulator key by default.

Here is the section from **docker-compose.yml**

```yaml
  customerapi:
    container_name: mycustomerapi
    image: acr.io/customer-api:master
    ports:
      - "20102:80"
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - CosmosOptions__Endpoint=${endpoint}
      - CosmosOptions__DisableSsl=true
```

If I override the account key and endpoint, I can get the application to connect using a real instance hosted in Azure, but I can't get it to connect to the emulator running on the host machine.

I've tried setting **${endpoint}** to the following values with no luck;

- **https://host.docker.internal:8081/** Fails after about 5 mins with the error `System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Connection refused (127.0.0.1:8081)`.
- **https://192.168.10.110:8081/** This is my local IP address. It fails much faster (around 10 seconds) with the same error as above.

I've also tried using `network_mode: host` with both endpoints.

- **https://host.docker.internal:8081/** Fails with the same error as above.
- **https://192.168.10.110:8081/** Fails after about 10 seconds with the error `System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: No route to host (192.168.10.110:8081)`

Comment: You can follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77522352/1690709) on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to run Cosmos with **AllowNetworkAccess**

This answer shows how to start the emualtor with the **/AllowNetworkAccess** argument.
[Azure Cosmos DB Emulator on a Local Area Network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55018321/azure-cosmos-db-emulator-on-a-local-area-network)
Once that was running I was able to use **https://host.docker.internal:8081/** and the container sprung to life!