# Trying connecting solution to "Azure Cosmos DB Emulator on container (Local)", does "nothing"

Tags: docker, visual-studio, azure-cosmosdb

**Context**

I am trying to run a solution. I did not create it and I cannot contact its creator (because it is some kind of exercise).
This solution has a React front-end running on API through Axios.
I do not know this type of stack very well.
Running the API through `npm start`, I get a 404 error when the API is called.

I'm not sure if and how `npm start` is supposed to be able to start a C# webservice at the same time as the React application.
So, maybe I'm going in a completely wrong direction at this point but,
I guess that I should launch the API from Visual Studio in parallel.

I know that I'm supposed to use local CosmosDBService to reach some database.
In the service `appsettings.json`, `CosmosDB.Account` and `CosmosDB.Key` are empty.
'CosmosDB' also has a `CosmosDB.Content` property (which looks like a long encrypted string). I expect that this is the database content (it should not be very big) stored in the JSON file, but I don't find much info about this precise property.

What I am trying right now is to connect the solution to the DB in Visual Studio through `[Solution] > Connected Services > Azure Cosmos DB > Right click > Connect` then in the dialog, I try to select `Azure Cosmos DB Emulator on container (local)`
(The other option is `Azure Cosmos DB` but I think that I need an Azure account for this.)

Docker is required to go further.
I install Docker (I'm on Windows 10). Docker requires something called something like WSL 2 Linux Services. I install WSL 2 Linux Services, but Docker keeps requiring it even after rebooting the whole system.
I read that an alternative way is use Hyper-V. I enable Hyper-V through Powershell. Reboot system. I uncheck WSL 2 in Docker. Reboot everything again. Docker now starts successfully.

Back in Visual Studio `[Solution] > Connected Services > Azure Cosmos DB > Right click > Connect` then in the dialog, I try to select `Azure Cosmos DB Emulator on container (local)`. The 'Finish' button is greyed out, but the 'Next' button is active.

When I click on the 'Next' button, nothing happens... No error, not other dialog box, just no info and no clue at this point. And the current Dialog is not closing. Clicking on 'Next' literally does nothing.

Edit: I noticed that first time clicking on 'Next' after relaunching Visual Studio, for a very brief moment, the cursor display "Loading" start and something appears at the bottom left of that dialog box (it just says "Waiting" and then disappears).

**Question**

*By reading the previous paragraphs, you may understand that I'm trying to run an application stack completely out of my "comfort zone". So I'm no asking for complete solution about this whole situation. (Though suggestions are welcome.)*

The scope of my question here is limited to:
Why clicking on 'Next' is doing nothing? What am I missing? How can I diagnose this?

Comment: Maybe instead of using this connected services thing in VS, try downloading the emulator to your machine and connecting that way. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator. No idea what that encrypted string is but maybe try putting the endpoint and key into those two values in your appsettings.json and see if that works.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. The Emulator is what I'm supposed to use from the start, which is why I picked the item with Emulator in it. The other it is "Azure Cosmos DB", but same as in question, clicking Next with this one selected also just does nothing.

One thing that disturbs me is that I don't have any DB to put in the emulator... reason why I guess the "Content" string might be the DB.

I'm also stuck at an error message that I have not notice yesterday. Assign configuration to [Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration].Iconfiguration says: (message is in next comment)

Comment: (following previous comment)
'The name 'account' doesn't exist in this context'.

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to connect with local Cosmos DB Emulator (Docker's container) by following steps:

1. Pull the docker image `docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/linux/azure-cosmos-emulator:latest`
2. Start the container (write this command in bash)

   winpty docker run --publish 8081:8081 --publish 10250-10255:10250-10255 --interactive --tty mcr.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/linux/azure-cosmos-emulator:latest
3. Access the Portal through `https://localhost:8081/_explorer/index.html`
4. Download the certificate curl -k `https://localhost:8081/_explorer/emulator.pem > ~/emulatorcert.crt`
5. Install the certificate `certutil.exe -addstore root ~/emulatorcert.crt`

You can read further information from these links.
[Connection String of Cosmos DB Emulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/emulator#running-on-docker).
[Connect Cosmos DB in Dev and CI environments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-develop-emulator?tabs=docker-linux%2Ccsharp&pivots=api-nosql#export-the-emulators-tlsssl-certificate).